# Why is redis namespacing with Sidekiq not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, redis, sidekiq

I'm running my production and staging environment on the same server. I'm trying to setup namespaces based on which environment that is running. For instance, I do not want my production environment to handle e-mails queued by the staging environment and vice versa. 
I'm using the same code for my local environment.

Here is the code:

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{Rails.env}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{Rails.env}" }
end
```

Whenever I use this code the e-mails are being sent to the Default queue but they are not being processed. If I remove the "namespace" part, everything goes back to normal.
This has just been tested locally so far.

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

I'm running sidekiq v3.3.0 as well as capistrano-sidekiq 0.4.0 for deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this on my own. The problem was that I somehow manage to add the following code inside `config.ru`:

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
end
```

Once removed, everything worked!